# Ошибка pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver' : file not found

Tags: python, база-данных

Имеется файл в формате `.FDB`
Я пишу скрипт, который мог бы читать его и изменять некоторые данные.

```
import pyodbc

query = "SELECT CURTIME();"

datab='driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 
Driver};server=localhost;database=PTKAZS.FDB;uid=login;pwd=password'

conn = pyodbc.connect(datab)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchall()

print(row)
```

Но при запуске выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect_db_1.py", line 8, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(datab)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю - FDB это Firebird DB, которая ничего общего (кроме того, что она тоже реляционная) с MySQL DB не имеет.

Comment: Попробуйте [модуль fdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fdb)...

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [примеры из туториала по модулю `fdb`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/fdb/getting-started.html#quick-start-guide):

```
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(dsn='/temp/test.db', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')

# Create a Cursor object that operates in the context of Connection con:
cur = con.cursor()

# Execute the SELECT statement:
cur.execute("select * from languages order by year_released")

# Retrieve all rows as a sequence and print that sequence:
print cur.fetchall()
```

---

```
# Example 4: Let’s insert more languages:
newLanguages = [
    ('Lisp',  1958),
    ('Dylan', 1995),
  ]

cur.executemany("insert into languages (name, year_released) values (?, ?)",
    newLanguages
  )

# The changes will not be saved unless the transaction is committed explicitly:
con.commit()
```